# How do I select an item in my WPF ComboBox based on my data binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

I've got my DataContext set to a Book object.  Book has properties: Title, Category.

I've got a CollectionViewSource "categoryList" that holds a list of Categories.

**Question**: How do I *select* the book's Category in this combobox?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>

<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Category.Id}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Category}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source = {StaticResource categoryList}}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

The code above displays the Book's title correctly and then it displays the list of category names in the combobox.  But it does not select the Book's Category. It instead just selects the first item in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're binding too much; you only need to set `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`, or `SelectedItem`. In this case, it looks like you're actually trying to bind to a specific object. If you're trying to have the `ComboBox` set the `Category` property on your `Book` and the current `Book` object actually has a reference to a `Category` instance that's in `categoryList`, then you should use the `SelectedItem` binding and remove the bindings for `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`.

**Edit**

To expand a little on how this is done, `SelectedValue` is designed to be used when you have a common piece of information to link your bound item with a property on the list source. For instance, let's say I have a `Book` class with a `CategoryID` property.

```
public class Book
{
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryID
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, you would do:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue = "{Binding CategoryID}"
          SelectedValuePath = "ID"
          DisplayMemberPath = "Name" />
```

`SelectedItem`, on the other hand, is for when the bound instance has an actual reference to (or, more precisely, an object that is equivalent to) an item in the bound list. So, let's assume the `Book` class actually looks like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, you would do:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem = "{Binding Category}"
          DisplayMemberPath = "Name" />
```

But it's very important to note that **this will not work unless the `Book` class has a reference to the same instance of `Category` as you have in the list**. If the references are different (even if the values on the classes are equal) then this won't work, as the `ComboBox` won't be able to find the `Category` referenced in the `Book` in the list.

The real problem with the way you were binding it up top (by binding to `Category.ID`) is that you're mixing the schemes. You have a reference, but you're trying to bind on the key instead. All this will do is try to set the value on your reference, **it will not try to change the reference on your class**.

Comment: Sorry yes, I just kind of threw it all out there. :)  SelectedValue + SelectedValuePath does not work.  Nor does SelectedItem on it's own.  Or even the SelectedItem + SelectedValuePath as Doug shows below.  

Ergh.  I think the categoryList's categories are somehow interfering with my ability to get the Book's Category (if I just bind directly to Category.Name in a textfield below it I get the wrong value.  But if I comment out the binding to categoryList the value is right).

Going to try his debug suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you.  Although, bizarrely i had to also do isSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=True to get it to work (I'm using SelectedItem as you show above).  Not understanding that part.

Comment: @Abby: Are you binding this list of `Category` objects to any other data source? If so, then that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To describe in code what Adam's talking about:

```
<ComboBox 
     SelectedValuePath="Id"
     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Category}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryList}}"
     DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

is probably more appropriate.  Generally it's better to treat `SelectedValue` as read-only, and use `SelectedItem` to choose which item you want to select.  When you bind the `SelectedItem` to the book's `Category`, it automatically sets the `SelectedValue` property for you anyway.

If that still doesn't work, you might want to check that your binding to `Category` is working properly.  In particular, adding a `DebugConverter` works well to ensure the value you expect is being bound.  [You can see the use of `DebugConverter` is the answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566060/master-detail-mvvm-wpf-not-working)

-Doug

Comment: This is true (though in this case `SelectedValuePath` isn't required) only if the bound object shares the same reference with the element in the list. If they're different references but share a common key, then this is incorrect.

Comment: WOW, thank you for the debug idea - that's awesome.  I used it and found that it is somehow setting my Category value (on the ConvertBack) to the 1st item from the ComboBox list.  Now I'm really confused.  But with a better tool at least, thanks.

Comment: and this (just to follow up) was fixed by adding IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=True, although I'm not clear why.

Comment: No problem Abby - the DebugConverter has saved my life on more than one occasion. :)